Is the Riemann surface $ℂ$ of the form $f(z,w)=0$? If so, what are the possible options for an everywhere-analytic $f$?
What are all of the possible options for an analytic (over some region) - expressible as a polynomial OR locally as a convergent power series in both $z$ and $w$ over that region - bivariate function $f(z,w)$ whose zero locus is the same geometric object as the complex line $ℂ$

They doesn't exhaust all of the (many) possibilities, but given any affine function $f(z, w) = a z + b w + c$, where $a, b, c \in \Bbb C$ and $(a, b) \neq (0, 0)$, ${f(z, w) = 0}$ is equivalent to $\Bbb C$.

@TravisWillse if $(a,b)=(1,0)$ then $w$ becomes the independent variable, right? I was under the impression that when studying Riemann surfaces it is conventional to always treat $z$ as the independent variable. Otherwise $w=z^2$ and $w^2=z$ would be the same Riemann surface, and I don't believe they are. Or is the convention I'm speaking of nonexistent?

It's true that often you want to think of a surface as defining a multi-valued function of $z$, which is probably what you have in mind. But surfaces $w = z^2$ and $w^2 = z$ define biholomorphic surfaces: You can get from one to the other via the evidently analytic (restriction of the) map $(z, w) \to (w, z)$.

@TravisWillse the basic idea of Riemann surface theory is to make $w$ a single-valued function defined on a topological surface, right? So $w=z^2$ is not the same Riemann surface as $w=z^{1/2}$ A biholomorphic map between them exists, but does that necessarily mean they are exactly the same Riemann surface?

I would not say that is the basic idea of Riemann surface theory---doing what you say is not always possible! The answer to your second question depends on what you mean by "exactly the same", and "biholomorphic" is arguably the most natural answer to that.

Would you please name an example where a single $w$ value cannot be determined by simply specifying a point on the topological surface? All of the examples I can think of satisfy this condition. I've been told that the square root Riemann surface, the natural log Riemann surface and any compact Riemann surface are such that $w$ can always be determined by simply specifying a point on the topological surface.

@TravisWillse: Your very first comment would be a good answer to this question. The OP's followup questions would be good candidates for followup posts.

@SimonM: Your last comment is far beyond the scope of your post, but as said it might be a good candidate for a followup post.

If this is still in flux, could you please edit the question to specify what you mean by (i) continuously differentiable (real $C^{1}$, holomorphic, polynomial, something else), and (ii) isomorphic to (biholomorphic to, biholomorphic to by projection to a coordinate axis, something else)? As worded it's hard (for me, at least) to understand what's being asked. <> For example, if $\phi$ is an entire function of one variable, and $f(z, w) = w - \phi(z)$, then the zero locus of $f$ is the graph of $\phi$, which is biholomorphic to $\mathbf{C}$. Many other examples exist.

One calls such functions holomorphic. And the word "isometric" is surely wrong in this context. If you really want to use it, clarify its meaning because it has two different meanings.

@MoisheKohan the current best answer is holomorphic in neither $z$ nor $w$? Is that answer wrong, then? Also, I updated "isometric" to "having the same geometry as the complex line $ℂ^1$"

"Same geometry" is very ambiguous. Complex linear functions are, of course, holomorphic. Given your interests, I suggest you do some reading in complex analysis of several variables (say, Krantz' book).

ah, I was only familiar with the use of "holomorphic" in the context of the Cauchy-Riemann equations being satisfied for some $f(z,z̄)$ my apologies

Given any affine function
$$f(z,w) = a z + b w + c, \qquad a, b, c \in \Bbb C \quad \textrm{and} \quad (a,b) \neq (0,0) ,$$ the Riemann surface
$$\{f(z, w) = 0\}$$
is biholomorphic to $\Bbb C$, in fact by a $\Bbb C$-linear map.

This seems analogous to saying that any plane in $ℝ^3$ is the same geometric object as the $xy$-plane. Are the two situations analogous?

Yes, for a suitable notion of "same" (e.g., isometry of affine spaces). A closer analogue is the statement that $\Bbb R$ is isometric to any line in $\Bbb R^2$, in that the surfaces ${f(z, w) = 0}$ in my answer are precisely the complex lines in $\Bbb C^2$.

The only reason I haven't marked this as the accepted answer is that - as you said - your answer does not exhaust all the possibilities.

That's fine, of course---you should wait until someone answers the question to your satisfaction. For someone to write a more complete answer, it would be helpful if you stated precisely which class of functions $f(z, w)$ is allowed.

I don't know what you mean by 'class', but I think what I had in mind is to apply the least amount of restrictions possible

By "class" I just mean a description of the restrictions. For example, you probably want $F$ to be at least continuously differentiable (regarded as a real function).

You're not going to get any kind of good description of all the other possibilities, until you get to something really high powered such as the Riemann mapping theorem, and I would say that an answer going in that direction is a gigantic overkill for this particular post.

That's fair. I have a very similar but more specific question that I'm far more interested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4909286/is-the-riemann-surface-zz-in%e2%84%82-of-the-form-fz-w-0-where-f-z-0-if-so

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$Not exactly an answer, but too long for a comment.
My best surmise of the underlying intent, using terminology that may or may not have been present in these questions (including the linked question) is to clarify relationships between

Riemann surfaces construed as "multi-valued holomorphic functions."
Riemann surfaces as holomorphic zero sets in the complex Cartesian plane $\Cpx^{2}$ with coordinates $(z, w)$ and $w$ a "function" of $z$.
Abstract Riemann surfaces (up to biholomorphism).
The complex line $\Cpx$, perhaps including its Euclidean (Kähler) metric.

The distinction between 1.–3. is resolved by Frank's answer here.
I read this question as getting at item 4. Travis's answer describes an arbitrary complex line in $\Cpx^{2}$ as the zero locus of a holomorphic function of two variables.

The main point of this remark is: The automorphism (biholomorphism) group of $\Cpx^{2}$ is infinite-dimensional.[*] Consequently, there is no reason to expect an explicit classification of zero loci that are biholomorphic to $\Cpx$.
[*] This sharply contrasts with the one-dimensional situation: The automorphism group of $\Cpx$ is two-dimensional, comprising invertible affine functions; $z \mapsto az + b$ with $a$, $b$ complex and $a \neq 0$.
Fix a holomorphic function $f:\Cpx^{2} \to \Cpx$ whose zero set $Z_{f} := \{(z, w) : f(z, w) = 0\}$ is a bijective holomorphic image of $\Cpx$.
Lemma 1: If $b:\Cpx^{2} \to \Cpx^{2}$ is a biholomorphism (holomorphic bijection with holomorphic inverse), then the image $b(Z_{f})$ is the zero set of the holomorphic function $f \circ b^{-1}$; that is, $b(Z_{f}) = Z_{f \circ b^{-1}}$. Further, $b(Z_{f})$ is a bijective holomorphic image of $\Cpx$.
The proof is a short exercise with definitions:

 Proof: For all complex $z$ and $w$, we have \begin{align*}  (z, w) \in Z_{f}\quad  &\text{if and only if}\quad f(z, w) = 0 \\  &\text{if and only if}\quad (f \circ b^{-1})\bigl(b(z, w)\bigr) = 0 \\  &\text{if and only if}\quad b(z, w) \in Z_{f \circ b^{-1}}.\end{align*}In words, $b(Z_{f})$ is precisely the zero set of $f \circ b^{-1}$.

Further:

 If $\phi:\Cpx \to \Cpx^{2}$ is a holomorphic injection with image $Z_{f}$, then $b \circ \phi$ is a holomorphic injection with image b($Z_{f})$.

Lemma 2: Suppose $\psi$ is an entire function of one variable. The "shear" mappings
\begin{align*}
  S_{\psi}^{1}(z, w) = \bigl(z, w + \psi(z)\bigr), \\
  S_{\psi}^{2}(z, w) = \bigl(z + \psi(w), w\bigr)
\end{align*}
are biholomorphisms of $\Cpx^{2}$.
Again, the proof is a short exercise:

 Proof: Each map has holomorphic components. Further, each is explicitly (holomorphically) invertible, e.g., $S_{-\psi}^{1}$ is the inverse of $S_{\psi}^{1}$, so each is bijective with holomorphic inverse.

Since a composition of biholomorphisms of $\Cpx^{2}$ is a biholomorphism of $\Cpx^{2}$, there are A Lot of holomorphic zero sets in $\Cpx^{2}$ biholomorphic to $\Cpx$.
Our favorite entire function is zero: $\phi(z) = 0$ for all complex $z$. The corresponding zero set is the $z$-axis, $\{(z, 0) : z \in \Cpx\}$, the zero set of $f(z, w) = w$.
Now take an entire function such as $\psi(z) = z^{2} - 1$, and see what happens to the $z$-axis as we alternately compose with the holomorphic shears by $\psi$ along the second and first axis:

On one hand, we're staying safely within the realm of Riemann surfaces biholomorphic to $\Cpx$. On the other, in nearly the simplest situation, we've veered into chaotic complex dymanics (iteration of quadratic mappings).
