Examples of Riemann surfaces such that a given point on the surface does not necessarily determine a unique value of $w$
If you Google search
The basic idea of Riemann surface theory is to replace the domain
of a multi-valued function with a Riemann surface to make it single-valued $\tag1$
then you will find many, many online resources that claim (1) is true
Having always believed (1) to be true, my understanding is the following:
For any Riemann surface which is the zero locus of $f(z,w)$, a unique $w$ can always be determined by specifying a point on the topological surface, because $w$ is a single-valued function with respect to the topological surface. $\tag2$
Now, having been told that this is not always the case, I'd like to know what a counterexample might look like.
Additionally, are such counterexamples deemed pathological in the context of Riemann surface theory?
If such counterexamples are neither rare nor pathological, then why do so, so, so many online resources make the claim that (1) is true?

A point on the surface certainly specifies a unique $w$; by definition, a point on the surface is a pair of coordinates $(z, w)$.

@Frank I thought so, but two MSE users with high reputation have told me otherwise. Would you kindly take a look at my other question, where two users seem to agree that this is not always the case? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4909155/is-the-riemann-surface-%e2%84%82-of-the-form-fz-w-0-if-so-what-are-the-possible

Could you point me to the comment that says this is the case? I can't find anything saying that $w$ is not unique.

Travis said "I would not say that is the basic idea of Riemann surface theory---doing what you say is not always possible! The answer to your second question depends on what you mean by "exactly the same", and "biholomorphic" is arguably the most natural answer to that"

It seems you're misunderstanding a few concepts here. I'll try to write an answer that will hopefully clarify things.

To be clear, I do understand that it's trivial to see that $(z,w)$ defines a single $w$ by definition. What I've interpreted from Travis is that (2) is untrue in general, which goes against what I've learned.

Part (2) "in general"  is just too vague to be either true or false. Try to formulate mathematically precise questions.

@MoisheKohan "in general" has a precise meaning in mathematics. "In the general case" "not in some specific case but in all possible cases". Should I rephrase to "in the most general case"? or "the case with the greatest degree of generality"?

@MoisheKohan does "in general" not precisely mean the same as "in all possible cases"?

What does $w$ mean "in all possible cases"? You should state your question in terms of surfaces and functions.

@SimonM Like you say, of course if you have a Riemann surface---indeed any subset---$\Sigma \subset \Bbb C^2$ then (the restriction) of the projection map $(z, w) \mapsto w$ is a function on $\Sigma$. By "not always possible" I meant something more general, roughly in the direction of Moishe Kohan's last comment. In any case it looks like Frank's (good) answer had addressed some of your questions effectively.

While multi-valued functions were Riemann's original motivation for developing Riemann surfaces, the modern theory of Riemann surfaces goes far beyond Riemann's original motivation. In fact, if you are to pick up a book on Riemann surfaces written in the past 50 years, it may not even mention multi-valued functions at all! If you want to learn more about Riemann surfaces beyond what you would see in an introductory complex analysis class, I would recommend forgetting this interpretation because it does not show up very much.
So what is a Riemann surface then? The definition in its full glory is as follows: a Riemann surface is a topological space $S$ which admits an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ and a collection of so-called coordinate charts $\{\phi_\alpha\}$, which are homeomorphisms $\phi_\alpha : U_\alpha \to V_\alpha$ onto open subsets $V_\alpha \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, satisfying the condition that the transition maps $\phi_\beta \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}$ are holomorphic for all $\alpha, \beta$.
If that definition didn't make sense, don't worry too much. The main point is that a Riemann surface is a topological surface with some sort of "holomorphic structure." In particular, this holomorphic structure should allow you to define "holomorphic functions" $S \to \mathbb{C}$ on our Riemann surface, or more generally, holomorphic functions $S \to S'$ for any other Riemann surface $S'$. Thus, we can say when two Riemann surfaces $S$ and $S'$ are biholomorphic, in which case we usually treat $S$ and $S'$ as the same Riemann surface. This idea may help clarify your previous question.
Some basic examples of Riemann surfaces are $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{D}$ (the unit disk), $\mathbb{H}$ (the upper half-plane), or more generally any open subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. An example of a Riemann surface which is not an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$. Perhaps surprisingly, a torus (the surface of a donut) is a Riemann surface; in fact, there is a whole infinite family of tori which are distinct as Riemann surfaces. More generally, any genus $g$ surface (i.e., the surface of a $g$-holed donut) is a Riemann surface.
Another good way of generating Riemann surfaces is what you mentioned in your post: given a holomorphic function $f : \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$, the zero locus $Z = \{(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \mid f(z, w) = 0\}$ is often a Riemann surface. Note that it is possible $Z$ is not a Riemann surface since it in general can have "singularities." For example, if $f$ is the function $f(z, w) = w^2 - z^3$, then $Z$ will have a singularity at the origin $(0, 0)$ (without me defining what a singularity is, can you see why?). This is never an issue in practice since you can always remove the singularity; in our example, $Z - \{(0, 0)\}$ is a valid Riemann surface. Note that not all Riemann surfaces arise as the zero locus of a function $f$; in fact, the Riemann sphere and all the genus $g$ Riemann surfaces I mentioned in the previous paragraph are not zero loci in this sense. Meanwhile, there is certainly nothing "pathological" about any of these examples.
I hope this gives you a good idea of what Riemann surfaces really are, and how a large class of Riemann surfaces have nothing to do with multi-valued functions. I believe the reason that the multi-valued function perspective is so pervasive on the Internet is that it is much easier to explain and motivate (cf. the definition of a Riemann surface I gave above).

I'm aware than only nonsingular algebraic plane curves give rise to Riemann surfaces, and I have a lot of experience calculating the genus of an algebraic plane curve with singularities. To be clear, given that I'm specifying a special circumstance, (2) is correct, right?

@SimonM Yes, (2) is correct by definition. If you understand what I wrote here, then you should be able to see that the commenters on your previous post did not say anything in objection to (2).

yes, I see the difference now. That said, I don't think I'll be studying abstract Riemann surfaces any time soon. I first want to be completely comfortable with doing calculus on Riemann surfaces which are the zero loci of bivariate functions, particularly bivariate polynomials. My impression is that if I've never done calculus on a Riemann surface then I should first start with Riemann surfaces which are the zero loci of bivariate polynomials. Is that generally advisable? Or not necessarily?

It really depends on your goals. There’s no need to have done calculus on Riemann surfaces before learning about Riemann surfaces. On the other hand, it would be advisable to know a bit of topology (and a decent amount of complex analysis) first. Note that the theory of Riemann surfaces should be distinguished from the theory of curves in algebraic geometry. The two are very related but use two completely different languages. (It seems you’re somewhat familiar with the latter already.)

I like your answer, but am ... uneasy ... about the use of the term singularity. In my experience, geometers nowadays usually mean non-manifold point. In that usage, the parabola $w = z^2$ is non-singular, though it does have a critical point as a function of $z$ at $z = 0$, and does have a branch point as a "function" of $w$ at $w = 0$. If you agree, is it feasible to reword to clarify for posterity?

@AndrewD.Hwang You are completely right, I totally misspoke. I changed the example so that it actually has a singularity now.
